# how can solve polylang plugin arabic problem

Tags: wordpress

I am using Polylang plugin in WordPress. Everything works fine on local, but when I move to the live server, I am facing the following problem.

If I try to switch language to Arabic, a lot of "???" are being appended to the URL and I can't reach the page URL in Arabic, because it gives me "This page isn’t working" error.

Answer (score 0):

**This page isn’t working** - it's because you have those `???` in your URL. Based on what I researched, and other questions on WordPress community (https://wordpress.org/support/topic/arabic-letters-turns-into-question-marks/), it's a plugin/theme conflict with Polylang plugin.

So what I'd suggest to do is to turn off all of the plugins, then try to enable them one by one, testing again and again, so you detect the conflicting plugin.

If disabling all the plugins didn't resolve the issue, try switching to another theme temporarily. If it solves the issue, then the problem is somewhere in your theme's code files.

(do this on live.)